# Dense subset of $L^2$ of product space with separated variables?

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-measure, harmonic-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$, let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be finite Borel measures on $X$ and $Y$, resp.

Is it possible to find a dense subset of $L^2(X \times Y)$ consisting of functions of the form $fg$ where $f \in L^2(X)$ and $g \in L^2(Y)$? Can the subset be taken to be countable?

Edit: The answer is yes if for every simple function $h \in L^2(X \times Y)$ and every $\epsilon > 0$, there are simple functions $f \in L^2(X)$ and $g \in L^2(Y)$ such that $\|h-fg\|_2 < \epsilon$.

For the situation, I have in mind $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure.

The following argument gives something close but not quite good enough: If $\{f_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2(X)$ and $\{g_m\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2(Y)$, then $\{f_n g_m\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2(X\times Y)$, so that the set of all finite linear combinations $\{f_n g_m\}$ is dense in $L^2(X \times Y)$. See [Orthonormal basis for product $L^2$ space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105451/orthonormal-basis-for-product-l2-space)

Comment: Have you considered the set of simple functions on $X\times Y$ with the corners of their supports on points whose coordinates belong to the dense, countable subsets of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: @MichaelLee I had not. Does that work?

Comment: Yeah, probably.

Comment: Actually it is not true in general. In fact it is almost never true. See below.

Comment: Why do you say the result you mention in the link you provide is not what you want? They seem to be of the product form that you required, no?

Answer (score 4):

By $fg$, I am assuming you mean functions of the form $f(x)g(y)$. In this case the answer is **no**, such functions are not dense in $L^2(X \times Y)$. I will give an algebraic proof of this fact (though I am sure that analytic proofs exist).

As a Hilbert space, $L^2(X \times Y)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $L^2(X) \otimes L^2(Y)$ and functions of the form $f(x)g(y)$ are precisely the simple tensors $f \otimes g$ in this Hilbert space.

In general, the simple tensors are most certainly *not* dense in a tensor product of two Hilbert spaces.

Indeed, given two Hilbert spaces $H$ and $K$, we know that $K \simeq K^*$ isometrically, and thus $K \otimes H \simeq K^* \otimes H \simeq \text{HS}(K,H) $ isometrically, where the latter space is the space of Hilbert-schmidt operators from $K$ to $H$ equipped with the Hilbert Schmidt norm $\|A\|_{\text{HS}}^2 :=$ tr$_K(A^*A)=$tr$_H(AA^*)$. One may check that the simple tensors in $\text{HS}(K,H)$ are precisely the bounded linear maps whose image has dimension $1$. In general, a limit of rank-one operators always has rank one or zero (more generally, the rank can only shrink under pointwise convergence of operators; this may be proved by contradiction, first supposing that the limit of some family of operators has rank $k$ but all prelimits have rank $k-1$ or less; then by picking a basis for the image of the limiting operator, one may obtain the contradiction by showing that a certain collection of determinant-zero matrices converges to a full-rank $k\times k$ matrix). Now, as long as $H$ and $K$ both have dimension greater than $1$, there are certainly Hilbert-Schmidt operators from $K\to H$ which have rank greater than $1$, hence these cannot be a limit of simple tensors.

Note: This answer was incorrectly written before 18 May 2019.

Comment: Just to check my understanding, if $H$ and $K$ are infinite dimensional, then there are non-compact operators in $\text{Hom}(K,H)$. But any limit of simple tensors in $K \otimes H \simeq \text{Hom}(K,H)$ must be compact, so you can't approximate the non-compact operators. Right?

Comment: @RitterSport Yes, that is indeed what I'm saying.

Comment: In terms of an analytic example, I have been thinking about the indicator function of the unit disc. It doesn't seem possible to approximate that by functions f(x)g(y) where $f \in L^2([-1,1])$ and $g \in L^2([-1,1])$. What do you think?

Comment: What happens if $K$ and $H$ are finite dimemsional. Say $K = L^2(G)$ where $G$ is a finite group.

Comment: I also thought about analytic examples like that, but I didn't get anywhere. I guess geometrically product sets are far away from disks, so that should work. In the case that K,H are finite dimensional (say of the same dimension), then any rank-one operator is representable by a square matrix with determinant zero, thus any limit of rank-one matrices must also have determinant zero. So simple tensors are still not dense, even in finite dimensions.

Comment: I think its a little bit offtopic, what happens if we replace $L^{2}(X \times Y)$ with $C(X\times Y)$ for compact Hausdorff $X,Y$? Does it still cannot be dense?

Comment: @user124697 Still not dense in general. Consider finite $X$ and $Y$. Then $L^2$ and $C$ give equivalent topologies, so it's not dense. Even for infinite $X$ and $Y$ I am certain it is false.