# Clarification to proof regarding orthonormal basis of $L^2(X \times Y)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

In the top answer to the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105451/orthonormal-basis-for-product-l2-space/105486#105486) I am wondering why they are using the cross product and not the dot product in the following argument. I would ask on the question, but it is from 2012 so it is quite old...
They state:

> The way I would do it is first to show that $\{f_n\times g_m\}$ is
>   orthonormal: indeed, $$ \langle f_n\times g_m, f_s\times g_t\rangle =
> > \langle f_n,f_s\rangle\,\langle g_m,g_t\rangle
> > =\delta_{n,s}\,\delta_{m,t} = \delta_{(n,m),(s,t)}. $$

I am confused because I think we would want to show that $\{f_n\cdot g_m\}$ is orthonormal wouldn't we?

Would it also be true to say this...
To show that $\{f_n\cdot g_m\}$ is
orthonormal: $$ \langle f_n\cdot g_m, f_s\cdot g_t\rangle =
\langle f_n,f_s\rangle\,\langle g_m,g_t\rangle
=\delta_{n,s}\,\delta_{m,t} = \delta_{(n,m),(s,t)}. $$

Comment: I think that $\times$ is meant to denote regular multiplication in the post. It does not really make sense to talk about the cross product here since you're not dealing with vectors.

Comment: When the answerer writes "$f_n \times g_m$" they mean the product of functions.

Comment: Thank you all so much :) I really appreciate the help. I think I am starting to understand this stuff now. That was just hanging me up a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These denote the same, namely $(x, y) \mapsto f_n(x)\cdot g_m(y)$.