# Orthonormal basis for $\mathcal{L}^2([0,T] \times \mathbb{T})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $T>0$ and let $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}=[0,1)$ be the one dimensional continuous torus.

I know for a fact that if $\psi_k(u)=e^{2 \pi i k u}$, then $\{\psi_k(u): k \in \mathbb{N}_0\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{T})$ with inner product $\langle f,g \rangle= \int_{\mathbb{T}} f(u)  \overline{g(u)}  \ du$, where $ \overline{g(u)} $ is the conjugate of $g(u)$.

I want to find an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal{L}^2([0,T] \times \mathbb{T})$.

I would say that the basis would be $\{\psi_k(t,u)=e^{2 \pi i k (t+u)}: t \in [0,T] \text{ and }k \in \mathbb{N}_0\}$. However, I don't know what would be the inner product and how I would prove it (I probably have to divide by $T$ and integrate twice, but I'm not sure)

Does anybody know how to do it? If possible, I would like you to refer me to a book where this is done.

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=orthonormal+basis+product+space) finds this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105451/orthonormal-basis-for-product-l2-space.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a book reference for the orthonormal basis for the product space? ie, if $\{f_k\}$ is a basis for $L^2(A)$ and $\{g_k\}$ is a basis for $L^2(B)$, then $\{f_k \, g_k\}$ is a basis for $L^2(A \times B)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on kahen's comment, I think I came up with the answer:

For $t \in [0,T]$ and $u \in \mathbb{T}$, let $\phi_k(t)=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{T}}e^{2\pi i  k t/T}$ and $\xi_k(u)=e^{2\pi i  k u}$. Then

- $\{ \phi_n: n \in \mathbb{N}_0\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2([0,T])$ for the innner product $\langle f,g \rangle= \int_0^T f(t)  \overline{g(t)}  \ dt $
- $\{ \xi_k: k \in \mathbb{N}_0\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ for the innner product $\langle f,g\rangle= \int_\mathbb{T} f(u)  \overline{g(u)}  \ du $,

where $ \overline{g} $ is the conjugate of $g$.

Thus, if $\psi_{n,k}(t,u) = \phi_{n}(t)\xi_k(u) = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{T}}e^{2 \pi i (nt/T+ku)}$, then $\{ \psi_{n,k} : n,k \in \mathbb{N}_0\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2([0,T] \times \mathbb{T})$ for the inner product $\langle f,g \rangle= \int_0^T \int_\mathbb{T} f(t,u)  \overline{g(t,u)}  \ du \ dt $. It is easy to verify that the functions are orthonormal
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        \langle\psi_{n,k},\psi_{n',k'}\rangle & = \int_0^T \int_\mathbb{T} \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{T}} e^{2\pi i (nt/T+ku)} \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{T}} e^{- 2\pi i (n't/T+k'u)} \ du \ dt\\
        & = \tfrac{1}{T} \int_0^T \int_\mathbb{T} e^{2\pi i ((n-n')t/T+(k-k')u)}  \ du \ dt =
            \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{ if } n = n' \text{ and } k = k', \\
    0 & \text{ if } n \neq n' \text{ or } k \neq k'.
    \end{cases}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

Comment: This only shows that $(\psi_k)$ is orthonormal in the space. I think you need to have more functions for the set to be an ONB. For example $(t,u) \mapsto \phi_k(t) \xi_j(u)$ when $k \neq j$.

Comment: thank you, you are right!