Product basis on $L^2$
Suppose that we are given an ON basis for $L^2([a,b])$, $\{f_n\}_n$.
Then we know that $\{f_nf_m\}_{n,m\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an ON basis for $L^2([a,b]\times[a,b])$
My understanding is that any $g\in L^2([a,b]\times[a,b])$ can be written as $g(x,y)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sum_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\lambda_{n,m}f_n(x)f_m(y)$ where $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sum_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\lambda_{n,m}^2<\infty$. Is this correct? I.e. does the closed linear span property carry over in this way to the case with a multi-indexed basis?

Maybe helpful  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105451/orthonormal-basis-for-product-l2-space

I've seen that already. I do not see how it answers my question. If you think it does, could you please clarify?

I mean, this is the exact definition for $f_nf_m$ to be an ONB. If you already know that, what exactly is the question here?

Actually, that was my question. I have not seen the definition extended to multiple indices. Thank you for verifying this.

Multiple indices can just be folded into a single index, since you can just use $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ as your index set. There's no limit on what can be used as an index set for an ONB, after all.

Yes, I suspected that, but if the double series is not absolutely convergent a-priori then the way we fold it could affect the limit. I.e. a cantor diagonalization might yield one limit while using some other enumeration of $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ might yield a different limit.

That never happens for an ONB. The convergence for an $l^2$ sum over an ONB is always unconditionally convergent, which can be easily proved using the Pythagorean theorem.

Yes, that is elementary. But this feels circular, if we have not defined ONB for multiple indices. I would agree that this is the only sensible way to extend the definition to multiple indices however.

Just define it as an orthonormal set whose closed linear span is the entire space, if you feel the $l^2$ sum version is circular. The $l^2$ sum version is easily seen to be equivalent.

Thanks, that settles it.
